# How to use kibana with elasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

Would like to get assist on how to insert a query into kibana, finally display result on kibana. My search quesry is like following:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/_search" -d'

{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
   "term": {
   "service": "http"
  }
 }
}'
```

Thank You

Comment: Maybe my question isn`t clear detail. Apologize for that. Basically I just want to display how much of data-usage on http usage by each host, n finally plot a graph to display.

 Base on the kibana documentation, thy will using discover->visualize->Dashbard to create the display. Is that possible i can directly plot the graph using  DSL query n finally display result on kibana.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly build Kibana visualization using ElasticSearch DSL query.

You might want to try :

1. New Visualization
2. Write in the query bar : `service:http`
3. Add a bucket on the X Axis, select terms agreggation, choose your field for host.